# Single Sign In authentication to PHP app and GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

We have an application written in PHP / Javascript to manage PostGis-data that is displayed using OpenLayers and GeoServer.
Since access to the data is limited to authenticated users they actually need to login twice: one in our application and a second time in GeoServer.

The main login-page is located at

https://DOMAIN/login.php
and the GeoServer login is at

https://DOMAIN/geoserver/web/

What would be the best way to realize a single sign-in, so that the users have only to log in once at the main page and the username and password are passed to the GeoServer-login?

Comment: Do the users need access to the administration GUI of GeoServer? Or do you just need to restrict the access to geo data delivered by GeoServer?

Comment: Use session based authentication

Comment: @Mesa: No the users don't need to have access to the administration GUI. As You suggest the main point is to restrict the access to the delivered geodata depending on their role.